# How to run Nightwatch node runner multiple times?

Tags: nightwatch.js

Below some very simplified code. In my application I need to run the runner two times inside a node script, each time with different settings that I supply on the fly. However the second time I try to call nightwatch.runner, it will never run. Am I doing something wrong?

```
var nightwatch = require("nightwatch")
var runcount = 0

function run() {
    // the second time it gets here, nightwatch.runner wont run. the callback will never fire.
    nightwatch.runner({
        config: "nightwatch.conf.js"
    }, function(success) {
        runcount += 1
        if (runcount === 1) {
            // run again
            run()
        } else {
            finish()
        }
    })
}

function finish() {
    console.log("finish")
}

run()
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like Nightwatch keeps some global state between runs which leads to unexpected behaviour. To avoid this I suggest you to use `child_process` to spawn Nightwatch runners in separate processes:

```js
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var runcount = 0

function run() {
    // the second time it gets here, nightwatch.runner wont run. the callback will never fire.
    spawn('nightwatch', ['-c', 'nightwatch.conf.js'], { stdio: 'inherit' }).on('close', function() {
        runcount += 1
        if (runcount === 1) {
            // run again
            run()
        } else {
            finish()
        }
    })
}

function finish() {
    console.log("finish")
}

run()
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't run because most likely it tries to launch two selenium processes with the same port.

If you need to run tests in parallel you can do that from within nightwatch by specifying multiple test settings.
check it out here: http://nightwatchjs.org/guide/#parallel-running

Comment: Dont think that´s the problem. start_process is set to false ([by default](http://nightwatchjs.org/gettingstarted#selenium-settings)). The selenium stuff is running on browserstack. Must be something else...

Comment: @Hans this information is important and should be in the description

Comment: Yeah maybe I should have added it, but it has the same behavior when testing locally.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @akm solution

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    times = 10,
    runcount = 0;

function run() {
    // the second time it gets here, nightwatch.runner wont run. the callback will never fire.
    spawn('./node_modules/.bin/nightwatch', ['-e', 'default,firefox'], {
        stdio: 'inherit'
    })
        .on('close', function() {
            runcount += 1
            if (runcount <= times) {
                console.log('Running test #', runcount);
                // run again
                run()
            } else {
                finish()
            }
        })
        .on('error', function(err) {
            console.log('Error', err);
        })
}

function finish() {
    console.log('Test proccess was completed');
}

run()
```